# GGPLOT BAR CHART not sorting properly with reorder

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a dataset that requires a bar chart and I know the correct way to display this is in a decreasing fashion (i.e.; the largest values on the left and the smallest values on the right). So I used the following code to produce the bar chart:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(province,-gross_profit), y = gross_profit)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fun.y = sum) +
  labs(title="Profit by Province")
```

It does produce a bar chart and in fact changes the order as compared to:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = province, y = gross_profit)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fun.y = sum) +
  labs(title="Profit by Province")
```

The reorder code gives me:

[image: Code with Reorder in the X]

The code without reorder gives me:

[image: No Reorder in the code]

For clarity:

My Provinces column is a FACTOR type with 10 levels and gross_profit is a NUM type. I have a feeling that you pros will quickly see something I'm obviously missing.

Comment: You need to change the ordering of the factor levels, not just rearrange what order they're fed into ggplot2. `library(tidyverse); df$province = fct_reorder(df$province, -df$gross_profit)` then the ggplot code w/o reorder

Comment: Why `fun.y = sum`? Does same province appear in multiple rows?

Comment: I gave this a go based Jon:

`df %>% mutate(province = fct_reorder(province, -gross_profit)) %>%
ggplot( aes(x = province, y = gross_profit)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fun.y = sum) +
  labs(title="Profit by Province") `

It changed the order, but the bars are still wonky.Not sure if it matters, but I have 775 rows, each row has a province value (factor) and gross_profit.

I hate to do it, but I wonder if I should create a new dataframe that groups by province and creates a sum column of all gross profits then plot it.

Comment: This ended up working... but I feel like it might be inefficient:


`df_province <- df %>% group_by(province) %>%
  summarise(total_gross_profit = sum(gross_profit)) %>%
  ungroup()
    
ggplot(df_province, aes(x = reorder(province, -total_gross_profit), y = total_gross_profit)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(title="Profit by Province")`